# What's probability that $a \cdot r_1 > b \cdot r_2$, given that $r_1, r_2$ are random numbers and $a, b$ are constants?

Tags: probability

Given that $r_1, r_2$ are random numbers (decimals included) from $0$ to $1$ and $a$ and $b$ are constants, what is the probability that $a \cdot r_1 > b \cdot r_2$?

For example, what is the probability that $10 \cdot r_1 > 20 \cdot r_2$?

Comment: Are the two rands the same?  If not, are they independent?

Comment: They are not the same (else the probability is a moot point, it would just depend on whether a is greater than b).

Comment: But rand is not necessary fully independent. I came to this question using a rand in ruby, which is only pseudo random - don't know if you would consider calling rand twice to be fully independent

Comment: assume, however, that both rands can produce a random number in the same range (in this case, 0 and 1, where any real number between 0 and 1 is equally likely)

Comment: While it's true that pseudo-random numbers are not quite independent, neither are they quite uniformly distributed.  But if it's a good pseudo-random number generator, modelling this situation with two independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ should be a pretty good approximation (and in the absence of very detailed information on the specific pseudo-random number generator being used, it's the best that can be done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U_1,U_2 \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, then we want $P(bU_2-aU_1\leq 0)$. Since $U_1,U_2$ are mutually independent, then the joint density $f(u_1,u_2)$ is just the product of the individual densities:$f_{aU_1}(x)=\frac{1}{a}$ and $f_{bU_2}(x)=\frac{1}{b}$; hence $f_{aU_1 \times bU_2} = \frac{1}{ab}$.

The condition: $bU_2-aU_1\leq 0$ carves out a shape in the domain $[0,a] \times [0,b]$:

Let $X=aU_1$ and $Y=bU_2, \;\; b>a$, then we have the line $X=Y$, so the probability is simply the integral over the region $X\geq Y$:

$P(X\geq Y)=\frac{1}{ab}\int_0^{a} z \;dz = \frac{1}{ab}\frac{a^2}{2}$

Thus,

$P(X\geq Y) = \frac{a}{2b}$

In your case, with $a=10,b=20$, we get:

$P(X\geq Y) =\frac{10}{2(20)}= \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z = aX -bY$ where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d $U(0,1)$. Then $aX$ is $U(0,a)$ if $a>0$ and $U(a,0)$ if $a<0$, and similarly for $bY$.

You can start with that and adapt [THIS](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/StandarduniformStandardtriangular.pdf) to your case.

I hope this helps.